# Web API get query params

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got the following method definition in a Web API controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] Paging pageParams)
```

And corresponding Paging class would be 'something' like:

```
public class Paging
{
    public int pageIndex { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }

    public Columns order { get; set; }
}
```

Received request is **/api/search?order(description)=asc&pageIndex=2&pageSize=25**
which I'd not have limited control.

What would be correct *Columns* class definition in order to get the binding for the *order* parameter?

Comment: You'll likely need a custom model binder for this to work.

Comment: Can you control the request as well if you need to?

Comment: Not too much of a control on the request format. It would follow strictly OData if needs to.